# CDT Indexer cannot find std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, std, unordered-map

My Eclipse CDT indexer apparently cannot find `std::unordered_map`, **although the compiler does.** It shows the following "errors":

[image]

The "Includes" folder of my project looks like this:

[image]

How can I tell the indexer how to find `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: You must activate support for C++11. See http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/282618/787571/ for more.

Comment: The solution described there does not help.

Comment: Your include paths mention gcc 4.2 that is pretty obsolete (regarding C++11 support). Since you use auto keyword, I assume your gcc version to be at least 4.4 (gcc's C++11 support table tells that auto was added in 4.4).
So try to change include path according to the most recent gcc's include directory.

Answer (score 1):

For a solution to the indexer-C++11-problem in general, see the answer to this question: [Eclipse CDT indexer does not know C++11 containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131744/eclipse-cdt-indexer-does-not-know-c11-containers)

Answer (score 0):

**unordered_map** is under **tr1** namespace of std.

So you have to add this inclusion:

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
```

and then you can declare your variable in main in this way:

```
std::tr1::unordered_map<int,int> mapArray[10];
```

Comment: Not any more.  The C++11 standard requires a header `<unordered_map>` which declares `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Why does the code *compile correctly* using `#include <unordered_map>` then? This is an indexer issue, not a code issue.

Comment: @aschepler, even in gcc 4.2?

Comment: @Barmaley.exe: No, I agree with your conclusion that the OP is not using g++ 4.2, so the Eclipse configuration is wrong to search in g++ 4.2 include directories.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse Juno CDT and gcc4.7 on Ubuntu 12.10 and have std=c++11 defined. Still indexer was going nuts about unordered_map. Adding TR1 resolved the issue.