# Eclipse CDT indexer does not know C++11 containers

Tags: eclipse, c++11, build, indexer

I configured a C++11 project in Eclipse CDT to use gcc-4.7. It is not the default compiler on my system, which does not support C++11. In order for compilation to work, I need to pass the flag `-std=c++11` and also include the following header path: `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.7.2/gcc/include/c++/4.7.2`

Whenever I use C++11 container types like `std::unordered_set` or `std::unordered_map`, the CDT indexer complains: `Symbol unordered_set could not be resolved`.  How can I tell the indexer to resolve these symbols correctly?

This is how I have configured my indexer:

[image]

As far as I understand the settings, the indexer is supposed to use the compiler settings from the currently active build configuration. Compilation works fine, so why doesn't indexing, too?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As described in this forum post:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/282618/

- right-click the project and go to "Properties" C/C++ General -> Paths
  and Symbols -> Symbols -> GNU C++.
- Click "Add..." and paste **`__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__`** into "Name" and
  leave "Value" blank. Hit Apply, do whatever it asks you to do, then
  hit OK.

Comment: This answer was correct was older release. But going ahead (with newer versions of Eclipse) @selyuni's answer works. Trying the answer which was once a correct solution is only a waste of time. Maybe SOF can change the policy to put more upvoted answers on top than just the correct answer. :-)

Comment: @VikasGoel: Does this depend on the Eclipse version, or on the compiler/library version, or both?

Comment: @einpoklum - only Eclipse version

Answer (score 84):

Setting up `**__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__**` does not help in my case (Jul 2014, Eclipse Kepler 20130919, Ubuntu 12.04).

To fix C++11 syntax highlighting go to:

**Project Properties --> C/C++ General --> Paths and Symbols --> Symbols --> GNU C++**

and overwrite the symbol (i.e. add new symbol):

```
__cplusplus
```

with value

```
201103L
```

**UPDATED:** If you use newer version of Eclispe (as of 2016) and still experience the same problem, try value (as pointed by jose.diego):

```
201402L
```

Make sure that indexer is enabled in Project settings (**C/C++ general --> Indexer**)

Then reindex (**Project --> C/C++ Index --> Rebuild**)

if the problem still persist reindex once again. It should work now.

Comment: Although it works with plain helloworlds, it doesn't work with makefile project. Any suggestions?

Comment: solved it for me too, setting up __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ didn't work for me either

Comment: @nitrocaster see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24628885/52074 which I tested and it works for makefile projects too.

Comment: Worked for me too. Only added a __cplusplus symbol with value 201103L. I don't need to do the enabling indexer step.
Previously, setting up GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X didn't work for me either

Comment: setting __cplusplus to 201402L was the only thing that solved my issue in Eclipse Mars2

Comment: Works for Neon too

Comment: None of these settings are working for me.  Neon / g++ 5.4.0 -- I suspect the g++ version is more relevant than the Eclipse version.

Answer (score 51):

I solved this problem recently after some lucky googling.

**Click on your project and right-click->Properties**

**Select** "C/C++ General **->** Processor Include Paths, Macros etc..."

**Select** the "Providers" tab

**Deselect** everything **except** "CDT User Setting Entries" and "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings"

**Click on** "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings"

**Deselect** "Use global provider shared between projects"

**Edit** the box at the bottom labeled "Command to get compiler specs"

**Insert** into the command -std=c++11 so it looks something like this:

```
${COMMAND} -std=c++11 -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"
```

**Click** Apply and Okay.

[image]

That worked for me. You probably need to re-index the project.

Comment: re - "probably need to re-index": my tests show "you must re-index"

Comment: I tested this with makefile projects and this solution works.

Comment: It was suffice for me to simple move `GCC Built-int Compiller Settings` to the very top of this list

Comment: You can also set this as workspace configuration, so C++11 will be enabled in all your new projects.

Comment: @Vasilly.Prokopyev thanks! In fact, just disabling "contributed pathentry containers" in that list did the trick for me.

Comment: Really thanks, only working list of steps that really works

Comment: As of today, doesn't work with `-std=c++2x` but works a treat with `-std=c++17`

Comment: @BlairHoughton That is down to the version of the compiler you are using. It doesn't have anything to do with eclipse itself. Also I think the switch will be `-std=c++2a`.

Answer (score 9):

Or go to:

- C/C++ Build->Discovery Options->GCC C++ Compiler
- add your flags to the Compiler invocation arguments. like -std=c++11 -m32
- Clear discovered entrys now: click on Clear
- rebuild the project

After that ALL symbols will be updated with correct values and the indexer should work as intended

Comment: This resolved the problem for me. Note that on Eclipse Kepler it is preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Discovery Tab. It is also mentioned on the eclipse community forums here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/373462/909018/#msg_909018 . Really unintuitive and hard to find!

Comment: the m32 was just to show that you can add any arguments you like. windows headers for example have significant differences between 32 and 64 bit. So if building a 32bit app on a compiler that uses 64bit mode by default you add -m32 so the indexer is aware of that and parses the correct headers

Comment: The discovery tab seems to be gone in eclipse mars.

Comment: Discovery Options has been deprecated and no longer appears in the menus. [Eclipse help documents it here.](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_build_discovery.htm)

Answer (score 6):

The workaround for me, with a project that uses an external builder, was to define the symbol:

> __cplusplus

with the value:

> 201403

in the project's: Paths and Symbols -> Symbols/GNU C++.

This worked in eclipse Kepler CDT Version: 8.3.0.201402142303.

Comment: Worked for me (using a custom Makefile).

Answer (score 3):

See [this guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn83#Toolchains):

1. C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC C++ Compiler->Dialect
2. Choose "ISO C++11 (-std=c++0x)" in "language standard"
   [image: Language and dialect]
3. Apply and OK
4. Rebuild the project and it works:)

Answer (score 2):

The follows works in `Eclipse` `C/C++` `Oxygen`.2 with `gcc-5.5.0`

`Eclipse Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC C++ Compiler->Dialect->Other dialect flags: -std=c++17`

Don't pick up anything in the `Language standard` dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration helps me to fix the issue indicated in the original question.

Environment:
Eclipse(Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)), Cygwin64.
In case you have a different version of Cygwin, you can find similar directories as follows.

Step 1: Make sure you have the following two directories:

```
   C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\7.4.0\include
   C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\7.4.0\include\c++
```

If you don't see the above two directories, please launch your Cygwin setup program and install gcc-core, gcc-g++ and libgcc1.

Step 2: Copy the directory `C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\7.4.0\include` to `C:\cygwin64\usr` if you don't see above two include directories.

Step 3: Go to Project Property->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols
Make sure you can see the following two paths are listed

```
   C:\cygwin64\usr\include
   C:\cygwin64\usr\include\c++
```

Step 4: Property->C/C++ Build/Settings/ Choose Cygwin PE Parser

Step 5: Property->C/C++ Build/Tool Chain Editor Choose Cygwin GCC

Step 6: Property->C/C++ General/Indexer Choose Enable indexer

Step 7: Project->C/C++ Index->Rebuild

Now your eclipse should be able to see the C++11 types.