# How to use -std-c++11 in Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, mingw

I have this line written in my code

```
vector<GLfloat> cone1 { 0.0f, 2.4f, -11.0f, /*rotated*/30.0f, -1.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
```

But the errors comes up like **in C++98, variable must be initialized by constructor not by {}**

I have searched the solution that I should use ***-std-c++11***, but **I don't know how to add this in Eclipse?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17132670/2485710

Comment: @user2485710 didn't solved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this in a few simple steps...

- Right-click on the the project and select "Properties"
- Navigate to *C/C++ Build -> Settings*
- Select the *Tool Settings* tab.
- Navigate to *GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous*
- In the option setting labeled *Other Flags* add `-std=c++11`

Now rebuild your project.

<sub>Note: this assumes you did not create your project to use GNU Autotools or a makefile.</sub>

Comment: Awesome. You are the man again who solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I did this and my project ran successfully, but now my project builds 100% but produces no .exe file. So, I can't run my project.

Comment: Note to my future counterparts. I had to switch from the mac compiler to cross gcc for these solutions to work.