# I can't use std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-kepler

I'm trying to use shared_ptr and for some reason it dosen't work, obviously I wrote -std=c++0x and **__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__** in the right places,
and yet I get the error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>
> Symbol 'shared_ptr' could not be resolved server.h    ‪/ex4‬  line 16 Semantic Error

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what's your g++ version ?

Comment: show us the code and the compiler options

Comment: Should be easy to post a trivial source that reproduces this with your toolchain (who's version info and installed platform would be highly anticipated).

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error or a Codan (Eclipse's code analyzer tool) error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131744/eclipse-cdt-indexer-does-not-know-c11-containers/17132670#17132670 remember that the right inclusion is `#include <memory>`

Comment: "Are you getting a compiler error or a Codan (Eclipse's code analyzer tool) error?" how can I know

Comment: @user3198219 If it's the former you won't be able to create an executable from your code. In case of the latter you'll see red squiggles in the editor, but compilation will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse misses a lot of "standard" things, you have to build and let it read "-std=c++11" in the output from make. That resolves a lot of them.

**EDIT:** This looks like a CDT error, not a GCC/compiler error - hence this answer.

HOWEVER despite this it still misses a lot, for example `std::forward` I have never gotten to work, `std::nullptr_t`... loads, you just learn to live with them. It does put a different marker for compiler errors, 'though they both show up in problems.

I posted to the mailing list about this and never got a response.

(This answer assumes everything compiles, but you can't get CDT to recognise some things)

I've spent many hours on this, which is why I bothered to write this, stop you from waisting hours too!