# Eclipse C++ indexer cant find 'vector'

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc

I can't seem to cope with the `Eclipse Indigo` indexer. The project is a mixed C/C++ project with external makefile.

I tried following [this](http://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2013/october/article4.php) documentation, but my project doesn't have menus, containing the name "Discovery".

I tried adding the folder, in which `vector` resides: C:\arm_tools\toolchain\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\4.7.2

to the `Paths and symbols/Includes` list. Although similar approach solved the `size_t: symbol not found`, in the case with vector, it does not help.

The code compiles fine. However, there are red undelines everywhere, the indexer complaining `Symbol 'vector' could not be resolved`. What should I do?

Comment: Sadly this is one of many problems with Eclipse. People will likely try to get you to rebuild the index, resolve paths, disable heuristic indexing etc. I will not bother because it will likely not help :)

Comment: @scy7he, addendum to the question: I rebuilt the index, freshened all files, refreshed the project.

Comment: Indigo is a very old version. Could try the latest version?

Comment: @Ali, I just updated to Luna. Same issue with vectors. I wonder is my toolchain (2012 Yagarto) at fault, or the project settings in Eclipse.

Comment: @Vorac Sorry to hear that. :( I really hoped that an update would solve it.

Comment: @Ali, there seems to be something major going on. Creating an empty project lists `stdio` as unresolved include. If I add it's folder to `Paths and symbols`, I get `The selected folder does not exist or is not accessible.`

Comment: @Vorac Sorry, I have no idea :(

Comment: answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131744/eclipse-cdt-indexer-does-not-know-c11-containers