# Eclipse/Nsight (7.0) and C++11 support

Tags: eclipse, c++11, cuda, toolkit, nsight

## TL;DR:

How can I persuade Nsight that I'm using C++11?
In other words, where do I set the relevant discovery options?
Building with -std=c++11 is working, even from within Eclipse. I'm talking about the Indexer having troubles with defines.

## Longer version:

C++11 functions are marked as unresolved in the Nsight editor, because the __cplusplus define is 199711L, instead of something >= 201103L.

When I made the project, in `Project Properties > Build > Discovery Options` the `Automate discovery of Path and Symbols` option was checked for every language and every Build Configuration. There was a note on the bottom of the Properties windows that said that the discovery method is deprecated, so I unchecked it for every language and for every Build Configuration.

Now, under `Project Properties > General > Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.` there are system provided paths and defines (more precisely, provided by the Providers). In the list I can see the problematic __cplusplus. I can redefine it under the CDT User Setting Entries and indeed it will be the new value after rebuilding the Index, but then whenever I click something in the editor I get an error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Notifying selection listeners".
org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.index.composite.CompositingNotImplementedError
```

That route is a dead end obviously. Another option is to define the new __cplusplus in `Project Properties > General > Paths and Symbols` under the Symbols tab. I can see the "wrong" __cplusplus there as well. Redefining it there gives me the same error as above, after rebuilding the Index, when clicking in the editor.

Also, what the hell is the `CDT Managed Build Setting Entries` Provider? I don't see any options for it. Where is it configured?

When I try to use the `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings` Provider I see a field where I can input command line arguments, but putting -std=c++11 there has no effect, as that entry doesn't produce a __cplusplus define.

## Offtopic:

In other news, C++11 support is great with the CUDA Toolkit 7.0, on the command line and in the makefiles. It saddens me greatly that nVidia settled on Eclipse. Whatever I did with it, I've only encountered trouble with Eclipse. Takes me a week just to set up the IDE for a project. I hate it so much.

Comment: If you do not like Eclipse, why don't you use another IDE? You are free to use any IDE you want. Aside from that, did you try what is suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131744/eclipse-cdt-indexer-does-not-know-c11-containers)?

Comment: I do hate Eclipse, but I don't use another IDE because Eclipse (Nsight) is part of the CUDA Toolkit. I don't think any other IDE would recognize CUDA kernels and highlight the syntax accordingly. Let alone support debugging with cuda-gdb the way Nsight does.

Aside from that, I did try those suggestions. Most of them refer to older version, and some of them even suggest the same things I described above. And when I do them, I get the error I wrote above.

Comment: Not really. It's funny that when using GCC alone it works as expected, with `-std=c++11`, but not with NVCC. For example, C++ project is all cool with C++11 features, but a CUDA project is not. I stopped caring for it and endure a few red lines. I compile it with a custom makefile. Through the IDE only `make all` is called.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar problem with the indexer when using the native compiler; however, the cross compiler worked correctly. When using the native compiler, `__cplusplus` was defined as 199711L even though the C++ dialect had been set to C++11 and the index rebuilt.

The indexer can pick up the C++11 settings by going to

Project Settings->C/C++ General->Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.->Providers->CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings

and doing:

1. Uncheck *Use global provider shared between projects*.
2. Add `-std=c++11` to *Command to get compiler specs* like so:

   `${COMMAND} -std=c++11 ${FLAGS} ...`

`__cplusplus` should now be correctly set.

Comment: Which one do you mean with native compiler? GCC?

Comment: I mean the version of GCC that generates binaries for the system running the compiler. In my case, the native compiler is GCC running on a x86_64 laptop; not the cross compiler, which in my case, builds ARM binaries..

Comment: I can't try it out as I no longer have Eclipse installed. I hope that this is a correct solutions, and not something Nsight specific.