# how to cinfig CDT(mars) with GCC5.1, to resolve "std::thread" symbol?

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-mars

My host OS is:

```
Fedora 22 x64
```

gcc-g++ version is:

```
5.1.1
```

eclipse cdt version:

```
Eclipse CDT Mars Release V4.5.0
```

here is my simple demo code list:

```
#include <thread>
void func(){}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::thread ts(func);
    ts.join();
    return 0;
}
```

and this is my cdt config(wrong config):

```
Project Properties->C/C++Build->Tool Chain Editor->(use Linux GCC as current)
Project Properties->C/C++Build->Settings->GCC C++ Compiler->Dialet->(ISO C++11)
Project Properties->C/C++Build->Settings->GCC C Compiler->Dialet->(ISO C11)
Project Properties->C/C++Build->Settings->GCC C++ Linker->(add pthread)

Project Properties->C/C++General->Paths and Symbols->Symbols
->add '__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__' to GNU C++

Project Properties->C/C++General->PreprocessorIncludePaths,Macros etc.->Providers
->(Select only 'CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings' and add'-std=c++11' to command)
```

the result is:

```
the project can build and run successfully
but eclipse CDT always show error: Symbol 'thread' could not be resolved
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131744/eclipse-cdt-indexer-does-not-know-c11-containers/24628885#24628885

Comment: I already take the config of " __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ " but nothing help, this works fine on gcc v4.9 but take no effect on gcc5.1 tool chain.

Comment: Look at the specific answer I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::thread ts(func);` might be considered as function definition. Use `std::thread ts{func};` instead. Also threads needs `-pthread` setting for compiler/linker - like: `g++ -std=c++11 -pthread prog.cpp`.

Comment: It works fine in terminal compile, I wanna solve the issue of -----> Eclipse CDT can not resolve std::thread symbol.