# std::to_string() could not be resolved

Tags: c++, c++11

I have error "Function 'to_string' clould not be resolved" although others C++11 expressions are properly running. I use Eclipse Mars CDT with GCC-C++ 4.9 on Linux Mint.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

int main()
{
    int a = 123;
    string str = std::to_string(a);
}
```

Yes, I used -std=c++11, __GXX_EXPERIMANTAL_CXX0X__, and -std=c++0x.

Comment: Did you `#include <string>` and compile with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the code wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! what is with the colon after `using std::string`?   Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok, I corrected this small mistake.

Comment: `string = std::to_string(a);` will not compile as you do not name a variable

Comment: @ktośtam You probably meant to write something like: `string str = std::to_string(a);`.

Comment: `-std=c++11` is good enough - do not apply ` __ GXX_EXPERIMANTAL_CXX0X __, and -std=c++0x.`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok, it's now correct.

Comment: @ktośtam Don't edit your question to be a moving target! That's not helpful or constructive. I don't believe anymore that's your _real_ code now. Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your error, period.

Comment: @DieterLücking Not in Eclipse. [\__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131744/eclipse-cdt-indexer-does-not-know-c11-containers) [-std=c++0x](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/CDT/User/FAQ)

Comment: @ktośtam Nothing to do with eclipse. The toolchain version used might be relevant.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I edited, because I was pasting the code wrong and finaly there wero no code. Next I add "Yes, I used -std=c++11, __GXX_EXPERIMANTAL_CXX0X__, and -std=c++0x.", because I thought it is'n necessary, when there is "others C++11 expressions are properly running". My code is too long and I added that simple example, because it's everything, what make the problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It isn't working good without it. I followed instructions in Eclipse site and in others questions.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly likely that you forgot `#include <string>` or you forgot to specify the namespace `std::`

Comment: It is highly likey that we cannot tell with the information provided.  they could not be using c++11 which would also cause this issue.

Comment: @NathanOliver it is atleast tagged c++11 and specified in the question that other c++11 expressions are working

Comment: Yes it is tagged C++11 but if they did not compile with `-std=c++11` then that would be the answer and your answer would be wrong.

Comment: @NathanOliver Note that he specified other c++11 expressions are working

Comment: The OP has added code and it looks like that have both issues covered.