# Use shared_ptr etc. on Eclipse Mars OSx?

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, c++11, eclipse-cdt

I just installed a fresh installation of Eclipse Mars.2 on OSx 10.8.5, and I'm having trouble using smart pointers (share_ptr, unique_ptr, etc). The IDE shows a red underline, and when I try to compile it I get `error: use of undeclared identifier 'shared_ptr'`.

I have

- included `<memory>` (which gets removed by Eclipse's "Organize includes" btw)
- added the symbol `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__`
- added the symbol `__cplusplus` with the value `201103L`
- changed Cross G++ Compiler / Dialect / Language Standard to
  `-std=c++0x`
- added `-std=c++11` to Cross G++ Compiler / Miscellaneous / Other
  flags
- selected CDT User Setting Entries and CDT Cross Built-in compiler
  settings in Providers
- enabled the indexer
- tried fiddling around with just about any setting imaginable

And it still doesn't work.

I can use `shared_ptr` without any problems in both XCode and when compiling with g++ in the terminal. Also, I can use `auto` in Eclipse without any problems. So what's the problem with those smart pointers?

`g++ --version` reports `g++ (MacPorts gcc48 4.8.4_0+universal) 4.8.4`, in case that could have anything to do with anything?

I'm all out of ideas on this one, anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using this old legacy bunch of you-know-what? Eclipse is sooooo 2008...

Comment: Sounds like you prolly tried this but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131744/eclipse-cdt-indexer-does-not-know-c11-containers/24628885#24628885

Comment: @SergeyA What do you suggest I use then? I've been using XCode the past couple of years for C++, and it's just as much a "bunch of you-know-what" s Eclipse, if not more. I have used Eclipse for 4+ years for Java and I actually enjoy it way more than XCode. So what would you recommend?

Comment: @Galik Thanks, but I've already been there and done that (literally). Have tried stuff from like 10 different SO-questions, some blogs, and other random sources. Nothing works.

Comment: @BadCash, I would suggest CLion.

Comment: Choosing the Cross Compiler toolchain is probably the wrong setting to begin with. Try to change the toolchain to the native Mac OS X.