# Eclipse Neo CDT can't resolve methods that have uint32_t values as parameters

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have the problem that Eclipse can't resolve methods that have `uint32_t` values as parameters. The code works fine, it's just a problem with Eclipse.
Does anybody knows how to solve it? I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131744/eclipse-cdt-indexer-does-not-know-c11-containers).

To be more specific:

I have a class defined in `myClass.h` with a public method:

```
void myMethod(uint32_t)
```

I call this method from `myProgramm.cc` with `myClassObject->myMethod(value)`.

Other method calls are fine.

Edit: Resolving a call from myMethod from inside myClass.h does not work, too.