# C++17 support Eclipse Neon

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, c++17

I read [here](https://isocpp.org/std/status) that C++17 is feature-complete although the specifications are not completely ready yet. How can I use C++17 features in my code, especially in Eclipse CDT (Neon)?

Specifically, I would like to use the `filesystem` to be able to iterate over directories easily.

Comment: Try passing `-std=c++1z` to your compiler?  C++17 isn't finalized quite yet.  `filesystem` will also depend on your choice of standard library and platform.

Comment: Eclipse can't find `filesystem` when I pass `-std=c++1z`. I guess I have to find another way to iterate over directories.

Comment: Note that Eclipse CDT does not yet have IDE support for C++17 features, so while your code will compile, the IDE may show bogus syntax and semantics errors on code that uses some C++17 features, and some IDE features like navigation may not work properly on such code.

Comment: Also this answer should be useful (substitute `-stdc++17` for `-std=c++11`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131744/eclipse-cdt-indexer-does-not-know-c11-containers/24628885#24628885

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both libc++ and libstdc++ have a `std::experimental::filesystem` in recent versions.  I'm unaware of either having `std::filesystem` directly; C++17 isn't released quite yet, that seems reasonable.

`boost` has `boost::filesystem`, which differs in a few ways but is structured nearly identically.  Code written to use `boost::filesystem` can be relatively easily ported to `std::filesystem`.

As an example of an incompatibility, `boost` has a singular flag enum, while `std` has a plural flag enum bitfield with more settings.

You may have to pass `-std=c++1z` to the compiler, check your `libc++` or `libstdc++` version, switch which one you are using, install a new one, etc.  Or install boost, and use its filesystem library which C++17s was based off of.

Comment: In addition, you need to explicitly link against the FS lib by passing  `-lstdc++fs` (in case of libstdc++) or `-lc++experimental` (in case of libc++). This works for the latest gcc-7 package on the Ubuntu toolchain PPA as well as for the tip of trunk libc++.

Answer (score 1):

Although `std::filesystem` is scheduled to come with C++17, the current compiler implementations do not ship yet "official" C++17 support. As [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk) already stated in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44049042/1885002), recent compiler and standard C++ library versions have `std::experimental::filesystem`.

At least for the GNU compiler `g++` I can say that you do not even need to set the C++17 language dialect, using C++14 is sufficient! However, you need to link the (static) library `libstdc++fs.a` additionally.

Also, it is then quite convenient to define the  `std::filesystem` namespace, so that you can use the headers (nearly) as if they were finalized already:

```
// ...

#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace std {
    namespace filesystem = std::experimental::filesystem;
}

// now use std::filesystem ...
```

In summary:

- Let eclipse use c++1y (C++14) dialect, this is sufficient
- Link `libstdc++fs.a`
- Include `<experimental/filesystem>`

Comment: I'd suggest doing `namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem`, as populating the std namespace is not advised. There are a few valid cases to this, such as specializing templates with user-defined types, but declaring a namespace is not one.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Yes, you are right, thanks for your comment. I just intended my suggestion as "anticipating the upcoming standard" — never intended this as "final solution". Of course this must be removed in code latest, when C++17 is finally available. Also, your suggestion is the form that is promoted e.g. on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path.