# How to change C++ standard Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am making an Eclipse project, and I want to know how I would be able to select the C++ standard (C++11, C++17) for a project.

Comment: By "language level" do you mean the C++ standard used (like C++11, C++14 etc.)?

Comment: Depending what your asking, this *may* be what you're after? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131744/eclipse-cdt-indexer-does-not-know-c11-containers/24628885#24628885

Comment: @Galik, Yes, that is what I'm after.