# How to activate auto suggesting in Eclipse ?

Tags: c++, eclipse, autosuggest

I have a big project in C++ and I need to see auto suggestions on words. 
It doesn't work even on the same file and I have checked preferenced, it's marked all in "Content Assist".

Comment: Is this a proper eclipse project? I mean can it be built with eclipse or is it just a collection of files? Also In order for indexer to work in header file this header file must be included into one of the translation units of current project.

Comment: Have you tried to press the typical shortcut: Strg -> SPACE?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24628885/3807729

Comment: yes, I've tried and it doesn't work @xMutzelx.

Comment: @VTT no, it's a project built in linux and in Eclipse I have imported the files

Comment: Which eclipse do you use? Oxygen, Mars, Neon, ...?

Comment: @XMutzelx I use Neon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have checked `Window -> Preferences -> C++ -> Editor -> Content Assist` without any success and you are using a proper project. I would suggest that you uninstall your eclipse and install the latest version [Photon](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php) and retry it. 
Additionally you could write a bug report [(link)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) that someone investigates your issue.