# Adding compiler switch to Eclipse CDT Built-In Compiler Settings generation?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, c++17

I have a Makefile-based Eclipse CDT project, and under `Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. > GNU C++ > CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings > __cplusplus` the value is `201402L`

I have the `-std=c++17` flag set in my Makefile, so the actual value of this predefined macro is `201703L` not `201402L`.

Clearly, the list of predefined macros in `GCC Built-In Compiler Settings` was generated without the `-std=c++17` flag.

Is it possible to set the compiler flags that are used to generate the list of predefined macros in `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings` and trigger them to be regenerated?  If so where/how is this configured?

Comment: I believe this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131744/eclipse-cdt-indexer-does-not-know-c11-containers/24628885#24628885

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the same preference page, if you switch to the `Providers` tab (rather than `Entries`), and select the `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings` provider, there is a `Command to get compiler specs` there. You can modify that command, by e.g. adding `-std=c++17`. Pressing `Apply` on that page will automatically trigger the provider to run again and update the list of predefined macros.

You can also configure this workspace-wide in `Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Discovery tab`. The `Use global provider shared between projects` checkbox (just above `Command to get compiler specs`) governs whether a project uses the workspace-wide settings, or its own.